# XAMPP Apache shutdown unexpectedly. Seems not port 80 issues

Tags: apache, xampp

I am new to php and I have encountered this problem directly after a complete new installation on Windows. I do not have Skype on the device.

When I try to start my Apache in the XAMPP Control Panel, I get the following errors:

```
5:02:46 AM  [Apache]    Attempting to start Apache app...
5:02:46 AM  [Apache]    Status change detected: running
5:02:47 AM  [Apache]    Status change detected: stopped
5:02:47 AM  [Apache]    Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
5:02:47 AM  [Apache]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
5:02:47 AM  [Apache]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
5:02:47 AM  [Apache]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
5:02:47 AM  [Apache]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
5:02:47 AM  [Apache]    If you need more help, copy and post this
5:02:47 AM  [Apache]    entire log window on the forums
```

[Error Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hScMN.png)

I have checked through the Netstat panel and port 80 and 443 is not used.
[Netstat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Bgj2.png)

For safety, I still tried to change the port but it didn't work. I do try to stop the services on port 80 by issuing

```
net stop http
```

but it didn't work too. [Stop Services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5hPd.png)

I do try to execute xampp_start.exe but it didn't show any info about the issue. Then I try to issue the command

```
apache_start.bat
```

in the shell panel but it showed nothing too.
[Shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1Gjc.png)

I do have VMWare and Kaspersky in my device. I tried to close the VMWare and Workstation in the services.exe but it seems doesn't work.

How do I solve this? Since I am new any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try to change Apache SSL port from 443 to 4430. See [this video](https://youtu.be/BBPihW4gXoM).

Comment: I tried that before but it didn't work.